# How to activate intellisense in VScode? (c#)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just want to activate autocompletion in VS code. There's a lot of answers to that questions but **NONE** of it actually helped me. (so please *don't mark as duplicate* when other answers DON'T help) Apparently, you have to press "Ctrl+Alt+Spacebar" but this doesn't work or me. I don't see any option in the nav menu to toggle a completion mode either. Or maybe you need to create a file in your folder? I don't know! non of this worked and I don't even know how it did work when I've seen intellisense! So please help me find a way to do this, and it'll better if this would be **permanent**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you must have an internet connection.
Then you should find extensions sidebar in vs code(you can open it by press 'Ctrl+Shift+X' or open it in top of the screen, View->Extensions).
After that you should search for C# extension that made by Microsoft(search C# in search textbox and click on first result)
[Picture of searching C# extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdCoM.png)
Then install that extension by clicking on install button
Wait a few minutes to install (e.g it took 15 minutes for me)
Now you have C# extension.
After that you should close the VsCode and open again.
Now you have auto completion (if not, you probably should press 'Ctrl+Space' while coding)

If you want to have smart auto completion, VsCode doesn't have IntelliCode for C#. IntelliCode is just for Visual Studio.
But you can use [Tabnine](https://tabnine.com) or [Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/) extension(you can search and install it like installing C# extension but you should search tabnine instead of C#)

Tabnine is good but it couldn't help me like Intellicode in Visual Studio.